# How can add a library into visual web part 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, visual-web-part, 2019

I created a `Dai_ExcelLab.dll` to output excel file as image:
[image]

I had add `Dai_ExcelLab.dll` to my visual web part:

[image]

And using:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Export();   
            Dai_ExcelLab.ComExcel oExcel = new Dai_ExcelLab.ComExcel();
            oExcel.OutputExcel("c:\\test.xlsx", null);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
    }

}
```

Build Deploy is ok, but click button Export , it occur error:

> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Dai_ExcelLab,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
> dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x80131044)]
>
> VisualWebPartProject2.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.btnExport_Click(Object
> sender, EventArgs e) +0
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11762420
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +150    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +5028

How can add a library into visual web part 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually occurs because the `Dai_ExcelLab` doesn't have a `PublicKeyToken`!

So that, try to do the following:

- **[Sign the DLL with a strong key](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/signing-a-strong-key-to-an-existing-dll-that-you-dont-have-the-source-to-it/)**
- Add your signing file in the SharePoint Web App bin folder.
- Remove the old reference and re-add the signing dll reference again in VS.

Comment: Thank you , i only "Sign the DLL with a strong key", it is ok. when i build deploy, dll will auto copy to bin folder.